# Error occurring as : w0 Fail to read json file with error:No JSON object could be decoded while launching couchbase image using docker-compose

Tags: json, docker, docker-compose, couchbase

I am using couchbase image with base version 4.6.3 in docker-compose . But I am getting the below error while launching docker-compose up : -

```
couchbase_1   | SUCCESS: init/edit couchbase.docker
couchbase_1   | SUCCESS: set hostname for couchbase.docker
couchbase_1   | SUCCESS: bucket-create
couchbase_1   | ....2017-11-13 09:57:06,301: w0 Fail to read json file with error:No JSON object could be decoded
couchbase_1   | .
couchbase_1   | bucket: ., msgs transferred...
couchbase_1   |        :                total |       last |    per sec
couchbase_1   |  byte  :               251515 |     251515 |  3987233.9
couchbase_1   | done
couchbase_1   | /entrypoint.sh couchbase-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Making the Json file to compact single line resolved  the error.